# .Net date conversion to RSS date

Tags: asp.net, .net, rss, xmltextwriter

I have a date in String format,

```
 mm/dd/yyyy
```

I want to convert this to RSS date format like,

```
friday, june 01, 2012, 12:11:25PM
```

and i want to add this date value which is basically the pubDate to RSS pubDate tag, as follows:

```
writer.WriteElementString("pubDate",pubDate);
```

How can i convert this string to pubDate? any suggestions?

O/P

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>About RSS</title>
<link>http://localhost:27549/TTTT.aspx</link>
<description>The latest news</description>
<image><url>http://localhost:27549/images/ttt_logo.jpg</url></image>
<item><title>ABC</title><link>http://localhost:27549/Viewttt.aspx?id=217</link><description>zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz...</description><pubDate>Tuesday, August 30, 2011, 00:00:00AM</pubDate></item></channel></rss>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fisrt you convert to DateTime variable. For this you can use `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Then you can use the ToString method to output the date in whatever format you want.
Here is the list of [custom formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

I will post an example to help you.

```
string str = "11/10/1984";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string formatted = dt.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm:sstt");
```

Comment: You will find it in `System.Globalization`. It says that the date culture is invariant. Invariant culture is culture-insensitive; it is associated with the English language but not with any country/region.

Comment: I have an issue now, i get the date properly. ViewSource shows <pubDate>Tuesday, August 30, 2011, 00:00:00AM</pubDate> but I can see nothing in front end. What could that be? any idea?

Comment: If i just give writer.WriteElementString("pubDate", DateTime.Now.ToString("r")); i get the output ie todays date n timestamp...

Comment: I am not an expert on RSS, posting a seperate question with details of your RSS output would help.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dt=DateTime.ParseExact("06/08/2012", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
writer.WriteElementString("pubDate",dt.ToString("U")); // or dt.ToString("F")
```